# How to plot learning curve of cForest in R (party-package)?

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning, decision-tree, curve

I have used cForest to build a Random Forest model.

Now, I want to plot a simple learning curve that shows number of trees on the x-axis and misclassification error on the y-axis (like the one underneath). However, after much Googling, i still cannot figure out how to do this with cForest from the party-package.

With the randomForest-package it is simply done with plot(rf), but this doesn't work when I try it with a cForest object. The following error appears:

```
plot(myforest)
Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

Hope anyone knows this.

Learning curve example:

[image]

Comment: You may check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205664/is-there-a-method-to-plot-the-output-of-a-random-forest-in-r)

Comment: Thanks, but this only shows how to plot a single tree from the cForest. I am interested in plotting a learning curve like the one in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking to do this so I contacted the author of the package. According to him this cannot easily be done because ntree is not a tuning parameter but defines the quality of the underlying bootstrap distribution. I'm unsure whether it's due the way the package is written or due to underlying differences in the math between cforests and traditional random forests. If you need to make this plot and still would like to use cforests you could try running various cforests each with a different number of trees (eg with 50, 100, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000 trees) record the accuracy for each one, and then plot it to get a similar graph.